# Primefaces Single Page Application

Tags: ajax, primefaces

I'm intending to use `Primefaces` as graphic library to my project. But I'm unsure about something; is it possible to make a single page application with fragment identifiers in the URI?

In other words, an app that can use the backward and forward buttons to navigate between pages rendered by ajax requests (like this: http://coenraets.org/backbone-cellar/bootstrap/).

There are any way to do it with `Primefaces`?

Answer (score 0):

if you need to ask the question - don't try to do it.

The way you phrase your question shows that while you see the obvious problems (handling url fragments), you remain unaware of life-cycle of view and the backing beans. And learning the stuff on a one-page application is the last thing you want.

Consider yourself warned.